# assignments to unpacked array must be aggregate expressions

Tags: system-verilog, hdl

```
reg [7:0] num [0:15]={8'd64,8'd121,8'd36,8'd48,8'd25,8'd18,8'd2,8'd120,8'd0,8'd24,8'd8,8'd3,8'd35,8'd33,8'd4,8'd14};
```

This particular line of my code is giving the following error:

> assignments to unpacked array must be aggregate expressions.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `'` before the leading `{`:

```
reg [7:0] num [0:15]='{8'd64,8'd121,8'd36,8'd48,8'd25,8'd18,8'd2,8'd120,8'd0,8'd24,8'd8,8'd3,8'd35,8'd33,8'd4,8'd14};
```

Comment: Should not need that for a simple array list of elements. Your tool might have issues.

Comment: I agree, but I would guess this is likely the issue